# SQLALCHEMY set default False nullable True

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have read few SQLAlchemy answers here, but I am still not clear about two scenarios.

What are exactly meant by these and what is the difference between these?

- Setting default `False` and `nullable = True` for a column

  `check = Column(Boolean, default=False, nullable=True)`
- Setting default `True` and `nullable = False` for a column

  `check = Column(Boolean, default=True, nullable=False)`

I am having confusing thoughts.

**EDIT:**

Here is the logic I am trying to implementing.

```
class Checking(Base):
    __tablename __ = 'Test'
    check=Column(Boolean, nullable=True)
    def __init__(self, check):
        self.check = check
    def test(self):
        if self.check:
            print("Success")
        else:
            print("Failed")
```

It is always working when `check` is becoming `False` i.e, printing 'Failed' but not working when `check` is becoming `True`. It is failing there.
The same is happening when the column is set to `default=False`.

If I set the column to `default=True` it is working when the column is becoming `True` but failing when column is becoming `False`--means vice-versa of the above.

**PS:** This is not the actual code but it is similar to the actual one that I am trying to achieve.

Comment: null=True allows null values when it is equal to False it does not so no column value can be null/None, default gives a default value for a column if you don't pass a value

Answer (score 4):

`default` specifies what the default value for a column is when it is left empty, so `default=True` only makes sense for `Boolean` columns and will insert `True` if the column is empty.

`nullable` specifies if the value in the column can be `NULL` (or in python `None`) (which it will be if it is empty, without specifying the default).

Comment: So for check = Column(Boolean, default=False, nullable=True) default will be set to False when no value is specified i.e, nullable=True, right? Since nullable=True allows column to be NULL.

Comment: Yes, but with nullable=False, that will also happen

Comment: But my code is failing when the column is becoming True i.e, when I am assigning some value or True to it. It is working for False or NULL case only. I am not able to figure that out :(

Comment: Well it is really long. But I can share the logic that I am trying to implementing. I won't mind editing my question. Thanks :)